# Date Picker format problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, datepicker, format

How do i solve the problem where i got 2011-07-21 15:55:01 +0000 , but the timing is off by 4 hr, how do i remove the +0000? And I want the format to be Eg. Friday 12 June 2011 1:30 PM

```
-(IBAction)addButton:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *choice = [datepick date];
    NSString *words = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", choice];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Date Chosen
                                             message:words 
                                             delegate:nil   
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [words release];

    label.text = words;
    textfield.text = words;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    [datepick setDate:now animated:YES];
    [now release];
    datepick.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMMM yyyy h:mm a"];
NSString *words = [formatter stringFromDate:choise];
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) date formatter guide.